# How to write multiply character on a label - Obj C & Java

Tags: java, android, objective-c, special-characters

I need to write some equations for users. Among them are equations with multiply sign, like [image: in this picture here]

So, can anybody help me out?
I've been doing some google research, but i must have been using wrong keywords to search.

How to write multiply sign on a label in objectiveC and Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this UTF-8 character is what you're looking for:

```
String dot = "\u22C5";
```

Then just add it to your Label/TextView

Edit:
In case you need to find more UTF-8 special characters, this resource might help you:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm

Comment: Thank you, kind sir !
I will accept your answer in 9 minutes ;)